# warning - Instance method '-initWithframe:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')

Tags: iphone, xcode

Can anyone tell me why the following generates the warning "Instance method '-initWithframe:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')"

```
mainToolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithframe:CGRectMake (0,19, 320, 44)];
```

mainTollbar is properly declared in the header file with @property, and synthesized in the .m file

further down another warning is generated from **mainToolBar**: "instance method '-addSubview:' not found (return type defaults to 'id')"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

initWithFrame, with a capital F.

Comment: omg thank you!  The incorrect spelling still showed as a highlighted word in the code editor so I thought it was correct!